# Forward slash in window.location.href redirects to root url

Tags: javascript

I'm generating window.location.href attributes where the path can sometimes include a slash "/".

```
ImageButton.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "window.location.href='DynamicItemDetail.aspx?Partno=" & strItemCode & "&Decorloc='")
```

The final strings look like this:

```
window.location.href="myurl.com/products.aspx?_Category=130&Partno=WWS-AWT/SWD&Decorloc="
```

Unfortunately, since the item code contains a slash, window.location redirects to the root url. Is there anyway to tell Javascript not to treat the slash as a subdirectory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to escape the characters in the URL.
[encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) is what you are looking for.

```
var encodedItemCode = encodeURIComponent(strItemCode);
ImageButton.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "window.location.href='DynamicItemDetail.aspx?Partno=" + encodedItemCode + "&Decorloc='")
```

The resulting URL will be

`myurl.com/products.aspx?_Category=130&Partno=WWS-AWT%2FSWD&Decorloc=`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `encodeURIComponent()` Javascript function to encode the slash and any other special characters into a format that's allowed to be used in a URI.

A good reference for the function is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the slash as `%2F`

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You should URL encode the string, or the slash.  So, instead of "/" you use "%2F"